# Jenkins Parameters: variables as default parameter

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a choice parameter in my Jenkins job similar to this:

```
choice(name: 'CHOICE', choices: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'], description: 'Pick something')
```

Is there any way I could pass an array into my default choices instead of the static ['One', 'Two', 'Three']? Something like:

```
String[] DEFAULT_CHOICES = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']

choice(name: 'CHOICE', choices: DEFAULT_CHOICES, desc...)
```

————————————————————————————————————

**Edit:** How would I implement this in a declarative pipeline? I’ve tried:

```
extendedChoice(..., groovyScript: “return ${DEFAULT_CHOICES}”
```

And I keep getting errors. There doesn’t seem to be many examples on this implementation.

Comment: You can use the extended choice parameter plugin for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can do it in many ways.
let me give you an example of 2 ways you can inject choice parameters

```
def choiceVariableInjectFromAnApi=[]
node {
    ['a','b','c'].each {
        choiceVariableInjectFromAnApi << "${it}"
    }
}

def choiceVariable = [1,2,3,4]

pipeline {
    agent any;
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'CHOICE', choices: choiceVariableInjectFromAnApi, description: 'Pick something')
        choice(name: 'CHOICE2', choices: choiceVariable, description: 'Pick something')
    }
    stages {
        stage('debug') {
            steps {
                echo "Selected Value From Choce parameter are  CHOICE = ${params.CHOICE} & CHOICE2 = ${params.CHOICE2}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```